# ggplot changing legends' color when using scale_color_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code to plot a graph:

```
plotting <- data.frame(accs_1,accs_2, knn_values)

plot_2 <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=plotting,aes(y=accs_1,x= 1/knn_values,colour="darkorange"),size=1, linetype="dashed" )+
  geom_line(data=plotting,aes(y=accs_2,x= 1/knn_values,colour="darkgreen"),size=1, linetype="dashed") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("Training Accuracy Rate" = "darkorange", "Crossvalidated Classification Accuracy Rate" = "darkgreen")) + labs(y= "Accuracy Rate", x = "1/K values")

plot_2
```

When I run this code, my graph's lines don't have any color to them:

[image]

However when I changed the values in scale_color_manual to all colors like this:

```
plotting <- data.frame(accs_1,accs_2, knn_values)

plot_2 <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=plotting,aes(y=accs_1,x= 1/knn_values,colour="darkorange"),size=1, linetype="dashed" )+
  geom_line(data=plotting,aes(y=accs_2,x= 1/knn_values,colour="darkgreen"),size=1, linetype="dashed") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("darkorange" = "darkorange", "darkgreen" = "darkgreen")) + labs(y= "Accuracy Rate", x = "1/K values")

plot_2
```

When I do this, I get the colors in my lines but the legend's text is messed up:

[image]

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it,

I changed the color value inside both the 'aes' values to the same value as values in scale_color_manual.